# Regex for multi parameter endpoint

Tags: regex, node.js

so far I've built apis in this fashion due to lack of knowledge

```
/doc/:uri/:coll/:db
```

But i want endpoint which should look something like this

```
/doc?uri=/a/b&coll=mycoll&db=documents
```

Can you please provide the regex for this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the rules here? Please provide examples and post your attempts.

Comment: That's a querystring ?

Comment: for now lets assume 2 parms (uri and coll) are mandatory and 1 (db) is optional

Comment: I like your first url a lot more - it's more restful on the eyes...

Comment: But I have plans to build an endpoint which may take more than 10 params for advance search feature that I'm implementing

Comment: You'd generally not match that in multiple routes, but catch it inside one route with `req.params`